# Learning Locker and SCORM-to-xAPI-Wrapper

Tags: scorm2004, tin-can-api, learning-locker

I have two versions of Learning Locker installed. In one version the statements are received however I can't view any of my previous statements as LL seems to be stuck

[image]

When I use my new version of LL, no statements are received however I do get a load of errors.

`xapiwrapper.min.js:2 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 GET http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/profile?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F1…fileId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Factivity-profile 404 (Not Found)
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: GET "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/profile?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F1…fileId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Factivity-profile".
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/profile?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F1…fileId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Factivity-profile".
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 GET http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/state?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F10.…D&stateId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Fattempt-state 400 (Bad Request)
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: GET "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/state?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F10.…D&stateId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Fattempt-state".
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":"`homePage`is not a valid irl in account. ,An`account`must have a`name`and a`homePage`.,`agent`is not a valid actorIdentifier in params. ","trace":"#0 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/BaseController.php(114): Controllers\\xAPI\\BaseController->validateValue('agent', Array, 'agent')\n#1 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/DocumentController.php(269): Controllers\\xAPI\\BaseController->requiredValue('agent', '{\"account\":{\"ho...', 'agent')\n#2 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/DocumentController.php(30): Controllers\\xAPI\\DocumentController->checkParams(Array, Array, Array)\n#3 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/DocumentController.php(68): Controllers\\xAPI\\DocumentController->getShowData()\n#4 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/BaseController.php(53): Controllers\\xAPI\\DocumentController->show()\n#5 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/BaseController.php(36): Controllers\\xAPI\\BaseController->get()\n#6 [internal function]: Controllers\\xAPI\\BaseController->selectMethod()\n#7 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#8 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('selectMethod', Array)\n#9 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(Controllers\\xAPI\\StateController), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), 'selectMethod')\n#10 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php(962): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 'Controllers\\\\xAP...', 'selectMethod')\n#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()\n#12 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)\n#13 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#14 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php(996): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#15 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#16 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php(746): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#17 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/asm89\/stack-cors\/src\/Asm89\/Stack\/Cors.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#18 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Session\/Middleware.php(72): Asm89\\Stack\\Cors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#19 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cookie\/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#20 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cookie\/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#21 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/stack\/builder\/src\/Stack\/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#22 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php(642): Stack\\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#23 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/public\/index.php(49): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->run()\n#24 {main}"} )http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/state?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F10.…D&stateId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Fattempt-state
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 POST http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/state?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F10.…D&stateId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Fattempt-state 400 (Bad Request)
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/state?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F10.…D&stateId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Fattempt-state".
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":"`homePage`is not a valid irl in account. ,An`account`must have a`name`and a`homePage`.,`agent`is not a valid actorIdentifier in params. ","trace":"#0 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/BaseController.php(114): Controllers\\xAPI\\BaseController->validateValue('agent', Array, 'agent')\n#1 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/DocumentController.php(269): Controllers\\xAPI\\BaseController->requiredValue('agent', '{\"account\":{\"ho...', 'agent')\n#2 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/DocumentController.php(30): Controllers\\xAPI\\DocumentController->checkParams(Array, Array, Array)\n#3 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/DocumentController.php(80): Controllers\\xAPI\\DocumentController->getShowData()\n#4 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/app\/controllers\/xapi\/BaseController.php(38): Controllers\\xAPI\\DocumentController->store()\n#5 [internal function]: Controllers\\xAPI\\BaseController->selectMethod()\n#6 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#7 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('selectMethod', Array)\n#8 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(Controllers\\xAPI\\StateController), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), 'selectMethod')\n#9 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php(962): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 'Controllers\\\\xAP...', 'selectMethod')\n#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()\n#11 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)\n#12 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#13 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php(996): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#14 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#15 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php(746): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#16 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/asm89\/stack-cors\/src\/Asm89\/Stack\/Cors.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#17 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Session\/Middleware.php(72): Asm89\\Stack\\Cors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#18 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cookie\/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#19 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Cookie\/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#20 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/stack\/builder\/src\/Stack\/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), 1, true)\n#21 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Application.php(642): Stack\\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))\n#22 \/var\/www\/learninglocker\/public\/index.php(49): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->run()\n#23 {main}"} )http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/activities/state?activityId=http%3A%2F%2F10.…D&stateId=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fxapi%2Fprofile%2Fscorm%2Fattempt-state
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 POST http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements 400 (Bad Request)
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements".
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":["`test`should be a valid`Locker\XApi\IRI`in`statement.actor.account.homePage`"]} )http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements
jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET "http://10.3.0.171/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/models_html5/quiz.html".xapiwrapper.min.js:2 POST http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements 400 (Bad Request)
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements".
xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":["`test`should be a valid`Locker\XApi\IRI`in`statement.actor.account.homePage`"]} )http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements
yui_combo.php?rollup/3.17.2/yui-moodlesimple.js&rollup/1426267206/mcore-debug.js:24186 XHR finished loading: GET "http://10.3.0.171/moodle/lib/yui/build/moodle-core-checknet/assets/checknet.txt?time=1426596376630".
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 POST http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements 400 (Bad Request)
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements".
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":["`test`should be a valid`Locker\XApi\IRI`in`statement.actor.account.homePage`"]} )http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 POST http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements 400 (Bad Request)
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements".
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":["`test`should be a valid`Locker\XApi\IRI`in`statement.actor.account.homePage`"]} )http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 POST http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements 400 (Bad Request)
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements".
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":["`test`should be a valid`Locker\XApi\IRI`in`statement.actor.account.homePage`"]} )http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/apiwrapper_2004.3rd.js:615 SetValue(cmi.total_time, PT71.07S) failed. 
404: Data Model Element Is Read Only
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/apiwrapper_2004.3rd.js:615 GetValue(cmi.exit) failed. 
405: Data Model Element Is Write Only
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 POST http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements 400 (Bad Request)
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: POST "http://52.16.190.132/data/xAPI/statements".
/moodle/pluginfile.php/29/mod_scorm/content/12/scorm-xapi/xapiwrapper.min.js:2 There was a problem communicating with the Learning Record Store. ( 400 | {"error":true,"success":false,"message":["`test`should be a valid`Locker\XApi\IRI`in`statement.actor.account.homePage`"]} )`

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the LRS is rejecting the statements because the agent object you're using in your requests is not valid. It looks like you're maybe using something like

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "account": {
        "homePage": "test",
        "name": "test"
    },
    "objectType": "Agent"
}
```

Whereas to be valid you need to use something like:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "account": {
        "homePage": "http://example.com/test",
        "name": "test"
    },
    "objectType": "Agent"
}
```

If that's not the case, can you add the complete statement you ARE sending to your question. See [this blog](http://tincanapi.com/2013/06/05/deep-dive-actor-agent/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=blog&utm_campaign=deep-dive-agent?pmc=em-1) for more details on valid values for agents.

You also might want to look at [TinCanJS](http://tincanapi.com/libraries/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=libraries?pmc=em-1) as an alternative JS library and [SCORM Cloud](http://cloud.scorm.com?utm_source=cloud_scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm_cloud?pmc=em-1) as an additional LRS for testing content that doesn't work with Learning Locker so you can pin down if the problem is with the content or LRS.

Comment: The Appendices of the spec are also a good source of dummy content for testing: https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI.md#AppendixA

Comment: Thanks for the help I have it working now, as you suspected it was to do with the homepage not being a valid uri. I had it set as just "test" and when I changed it to be "http://example.com/test" it worked :). Thanls

Comment: Glad you got it working! Just to clarify for anybody else looking at this question "example.com/test" is also invalid. It must have been "http://example.com/test" you used?

Comment: lmsHomePage is not a valid property.